# SELECT Top 1 ID, DISTINCT Field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table sample table as follows:

```
ID | City
--------------
1  | New York
2  | San Francisco
3  | New York
4  | Los Angeles
5  | Atlanta
```

I would like to select the distinct City AND the TOP ID for each. E.g., conceptually I would like to do the following

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID, DISTINCT City
FROM Cities
```

Should give me:

```
ID | City
--------------
1  | New York
2  | San Francisco
4  | Los Angeles
5  | Atlanta
```

Because New York appears twice, it's taken the first ID `1` in this instance.

But I get the error:

> Column 'Cities.ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Post your whole code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this way:

```
SELECT min(ID), City
FROM Cities
Group by City
```

`MIN` function is used for choose one of the `ID` from two `New York` cities.

Answer (score 4):

You need to have your city in a `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT MIN(ID), City
FROM Cities
GROUP BY City
```

Answer (score 3):

More general solution is to use `row_number` in order to get other details of table:

```
select * from
(select *, row_number() over(partition by City order by ID) as rn from Cities)
where rn = 1
```

But for this particular table just grouping will do the work:

```
select City, Min(ID) as ID
from Cities
group by City
```

Comment: That's another solution I hadn't thought of - thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a complex scenario where `Group By` cannot use, You could use [Row_Number()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function with [Common Table Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms175972.aspx).

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT ID, City, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY City ORDER BY Id) rn
   FROM YourTable
)
SELECT Id, City
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```